# CocoaPods 0.34 - moving the local specs

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

With the introduction of CocoaPods 0.34 local specs became deprecated. But "tips", given with the new version, doesn't really describe - what to do with the local specs.

What I understood from the information and guides, provided there:
1) All local specs have to be moved to an external (i.e. git) specs repository
2) Specs repository have to repeat the special folder structure (./ - Specs -  -  - )

and here we go. If the pod specs I want to move actually shows specs for private pods, and the repo with podspecs is also private? How to connect it to the pod file of my project properly?

Thanks in advance for instructions or the proper links

Comment: We're using local pod specs a lot and 0.34 was a breaking change indeed, but I can't find any information about local pod specs being deprecated. Could you please post a link to this?

Comment: Here what I'm getting: "The use of implicit sources has been deprecated. To continue using all of the sources currently on your machine, add the following to the top of your Podfile:..."

Comment: Well, that means, that you have to explicitly say `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'` for remote podspecs storage, but local podspecs are still fine: `pod 'MyPod', :path => 'path/to/podspec'`